# Listing attributes in fields_for in Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, fields-for

I have a form_for, which encloses fields_for for a Party and Guest model (a party has many guests, accepts nested attributes for guests), and a guest belongs to a party. I have a form_for my Party model, that lists out certain fields for each guest in the party. My form works just fine, but I want to simply list the name of each guest in the form, so it appears:

```
"Bob"
   attending: yes || no
   meal choice: chicken || veggie || pasta

"Susie"
  attending: yes || no
  meal choice: chicken || veggie || pasta
```

Right now, what I have is just:

```
attending: yes || no
meal choice: chicken || veggie || pasta

attending: yes || no
meal choice: chicken || veggie || pasta
```

How can I just list out the guest.first_name for each iteration of the fields_for??? Clearly, my guests_form.first_name does not work.

The code for my form is:

### people in your party:

```
<%= form_for @party do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :party_id, value: current_party.id %>
  <%= f.fields_for @guests do |guests_form| %>

  <%= guests_form.first_name %>
        <%= guests_form.label :attending, "attending?" %>
        <%= guests_form.radio_button :attending, true, :checked => true %>
        <%= guests_form.label :attending, "yes!", :value => true %>
        <%= guests_form.radio_button :attending, false, :checked => false %>
        <%= guests_form.label :attending, "no", :value => false %>

        <%=guests_form.label :meal_id, "meal choice" %>
        <%=guests_form.radio_button :meal_id, :checked => 1 %>
        <%= guests_form.label :meal_id, "chicken", :value => 1 %>
        <%=guests_form.radio_button :meal_id, :checked => 2 %>
        <%= guests_form.label :meal_id, "veggie", :value => 2 %>
        <%=guests_form.radio_button  :meal_id, :checked => 3 %>
        <%= guests_form.label :meal_id, "pasta", :value => 3 %>
    <%end%>

 <%= f.submit "submit", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>

<%end%>
```

I've never used fields_for before, so any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You're using Devise? If yes, then:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <p>Hello <%= current_user.first_name %>, let us know your preferences:      </p>
<%form_for @party do...
...
...

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You'll need to capture the user_id in a hidden field so it is saved along with the selections.
And I would consider using checkboxes or radio buttons from collection.

Comment: I'm not using devise, and I need the first_name of each user in the party, regardless of whether or not that person is signed in. So, in my example above, if Bob signs in, but he and Susie are in the same party, Bob should also see Susie's name listed, as she is in his party.

Comment: So this is a multi-step form, first capturing the name of the person who is responding and the party he wants to attach himself to. After he enters that info he could learn who else in invited/accepted/declined and if he accepts can make his food choices. Googling 'rails multistep form' will yield quite a few posts on the subject and some good tutorials.